# Teamcity: Nuget installer is not fetching dll from nuget.org

Tags: teamcity, jetbrains-ide

Nuget installer is not fetching dll files for packages from nuget.org. Below is my configuration in teamcity.

[image: Nuget Installer Step]

[image: MSBuild Step]

[image: Nuget step is successful but I could not see the dll in the buildagent/work folder]

Nuget installer step is successful but I could not see the dll in the buildagent/work folder

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that these have come from a packages directory that is in source control and have not been restored from NuGet.org, yet when they were checked into source control the binaries weren't. The screenshot shows a file under source control - if the package had been restored from NuGet.org it wouldn't be under source control. It looks like you are using SVN and if I remember correctly then binaries are excluded by default.

If you check the NuGet Packages tab for the build you will see packages that have actually been downloaded (from an external source)

[image]

If you remove the packages directory from source control then perform a clean build this should restore the packages as you expect.

Hope this helps